# Space divergence/Stokes theorem on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, stokes-theorem, semi-riemannian-geometry

Setup: Let $u: (V,g) \rightarrow (M,h)$ be a map where

- $V$ is a Lorentz manifold of dimension $n+1$, $V= R \times S$ where $S$ is a $n$ dimensional smooth oriented manifold with metric $\sigma$. On $V$, we have a Robertson Walker metric $g=-dt^2+R^2(t) \sigma$
- $M$ is a Riemannian manifold.

Now if we have local coordinates $x_{\alpha}$ on $V$ and $y^A$ on $M$, we can define $du \in \Gamma(V, T^{*}V \otimes u^{*}TM)$,

$$ du= \partial_{\alpha} u^A [dx_{\alpha} \otimes u^{*} \partial_A] $$

We also use the notation

$$d_{\alpha} u= \partial_{\alpha} u^A  u^{*} \partial_A$$

It then holds that $h( d_{\alpha} u, d_{\beta} u) \in C^{\infty}(V)$.

Now look at an expression of the kind:

$$\sigma^{ij}[(\nabla_i^{\sigma} (h(d_tu, d_ku) dx_k) )(\partial_j)]$$

Now it says that this is, for each $t$, a "space divergence in the metric $\sigma$" and therefore

$$\int\limits_{S_t} \sigma^{ij}[(\nabla_i^{\sigma} (h(d_tu, d_ku) dx_k) )(\partial_j)]=0$$

Here, $S_t=\{t\} \times S$ is a submanifold of $V$.

Comments on notations:

- $\partial_t$ is the basis tangent vector on $R$
- $t$ is the index used for $R$ and other latin indices are used for $S$

My question: I don't see why this is true. I was told to apply Stokes theorem but I don't see how and why I am allowed to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Write In general for a one form $\alpha = \alpha_i \mathrm dx^i$, then

$$A = \sigma^{ij} \nabla_i \alpha_j$$

is the divergence of $\alpha$, which can also be written as

$$X = -*d *\alpha, $$
where $*$ is the Hodge star operator. So

$$ \int _S X \; \mathrm dV = -\int_S * ( d*\alpha \mathrm dV) = \int_S d* \alpha$$

and from there one can apply Stokes theorem.

Comment: Have we established that $S$ is a compact manifold without boundary?

Comment: No, @TedShifrin, not suggested in the post (yes so the integral might not be zero in general)

Comment: Well, the OP had $=0$, which is why I commented. The comment should have been on the OP, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  You define the one form $\alpha = \alpha_i dx^i$ and $A= \sigma^{ij} \nabla_i \alpha_j$ but $\alpha_j$ are only the coefficient functions, right? Shouldn't it be (to be the same as in my question): $A= \sigma^{ij} [(\nabla_i \alpha)(\partial_j)]$?

Comment: On the compactness of $S$: As far as I see, $S$ doesn't have to be compact in general. But I will add more details on $S$ in the question.

Comment: @User1 If $S$ is not compact and $\alpha$ is not of compact support, Stokes theorem does not tell you much.

Comment: My notation $\nabla_i \alpha_j$ is exactly what you wrote, it's $(\nabla_i \alpha) (\partial_j)$.

Comment: Ok thank you! I guess I can't avoid telling all of the details about this question (for example $f_k$ is of specific form but doesn't have compact support as far as I see). Should I edit my question or begin a new ?

Comment: You may edit this one. @User1

Comment: Ok, I've changed it now. I am pretty sure that $S$ does not have to be compact since later in the paper, it says "in the case of a compact $S$".